# How to add an event formAddNewRow to editable Datatable to create the fineUploader object?

Tags: jquery, datatables, valums-file-uploader

I´m trying to add a file uploader to one jquery dataTable editable (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-datatables-editable/)

I tried adding a div to the form but fineUploader keeps the state from the last operation.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
       $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
               request: {
                  endpoint: ...

<form id="formAddNewMedia" action="#" title="Agregar un elemento">
<div id="fine-uploader"></div>
<label for=....
```

There is a method to reset all UI elements to the state they existed immediately after initialization... but i think the fileUploader should be built with the form activation and destroyed after it´s closed.

Something like a callback fnOnAddNewRow :

```
 var oTable = $('#media_table').dataTable({
        "sScrollY": "200px",
        "bScrollCollapse": true,
        "bPaginate": false,
        "sAjaxSource": "/ajax_library_media.txt",
        "bProcessing": true,
        "oLanguage": {
            "sUrl": "assets/js/dataTables.spanish.txt"
        },
        "bJQueryUI" : true
        }).makeEditable({

        sUpdateURL: "update_media.php",
                    sAddURL: "add_media.php",
                    fnOnAddNewRow (function() {
                        $('#fine-uploader').fineUploader({
                        request: {
                        endpoint: ...
```

Which i think can be added here in jquery.dataTables.editable.js

```
        //Setup form to open in dialog
        oAddNewRowForm = $("#" + properties.sAddNewRowFormId);
        if (oAddNewRowForm.length != 0) {
            if (properties.oAddNewRowFormOptions != null) {
                properties.oAddNewRowFormOptions.autoOpen = false;
            } else {
                properties.oAddNewRowFormOptions = { autoOpen: false };
            }
            oAddNewRowForm.dialog(properties.oAddNewRowFormOptions);

            //Add button click handler on the "Add new row" button
            oAddNewRowButton = $("#" + properties.sAddNewRowButtonId);
            if (oAddNewRowButton.length != 0) {
                oAddNewRowButton.click(function () {
                    oAddNewRowForm.dialog('open');

                });
            } else {
                if ($(properties.sAddDeleteToolbarSelector).length == 0) {
                    throw "Cannot find a button with an id '" + properties.sAddNewRowButtonId + "', od placeholder with an id '" + properties.sAddDeleteToolbarSelector + "' that should be used for adding new row although form for adding new record is specified";
                } else {
                    oAddNewRowButton = null; //It will be auto-generated later
                }
            }
```

Where the dialog is opened with oAddNewRowForm.dialog('open');

Anyone with a sleep saving idea?!